# Create a new column and flag as 1 or 0?

Tags: sql, oracle

Table:

```
  PARENT_ID    ID   YR_MONTH    REWARD
1    1          11   201601        3 
2    1          11   201605        9   
3    1          11   201609        12         
4    1          12   201601        6          
5    1          12   201605        9          
6    1          12   201609        9          
7    2          21   201601        15         
8    2          21   201605        9          
9    2          21   201609        12         
10   2          22   201601        9          
10   2          22   201605        9          
10   2          23   201609        9
```

I need to create a new column based on the `reward` column. Where Reward is 9 put 1 else 0 based on the condition.

Expected results

output table -

```
  PARENT_ID    ID   YR_MONTH    REWARD  REWARD_STATUS
1    1          11   201601        3          0
2    1          11   201605        9          1
3    1          11   201609        12         0
4    1          12   201601        6          0
5    1          12   201605        9          1
6    1          12   201609        9          0
7    2          21   201601        15         0
8    2          21   201605        9          0
9    2          21   201609        12         0
10   2          22   201601        9          1
10   2          22   201605        9          0
10   2          23   201609        9          1
```

Comment: Your data is not consistent with your description.  Is it the *next* or *previous* year month that you care about.

Comment: "Create a new column" - where? In the same table? Or in a `select` query? Or a view? NOTE: "In the same table" is a terrible practice (not uncommon, just very bad). Calculated values like this should not be stored in the base table; if you need to use the flag more than once, you should create a view, and when the flag is needed, select from the view rather than from the table.

Comment: You say "previous yr_month", but the lag is appearing in the month *before*  the higher values, not the row *after*.

Answer (score 0):

> for particular parent_id, id check if there is no higher reward than 9 in any of previous yr_month if yes then 0 else 1.

I am interpreting this as "if the previous `year_month` is higher than 9 then 1 else 0."

I think you want `lag()`:

```
select t.*,
       (case when lag(reward) over (partition by parent_id order by year_month) > 9
             then 1 else 0
        end) as reward_status
from t;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
with t  (PARENT_ID,    ID,   YR_MONTH,    REWARD) as (
  select   1,          11,   201601,        3 from dual union all 
  select   1,          11,   201605,        9 from dual union all   
  select   1,          11,   201609,        12 from dual union all         
  select   1,          12,   201601,        6 from dual union all          
  select   1,          12,   201605,        9 from dual union all          
  select   1,          12,   201609,        9 from dual union all          
  select   2,          21,   201601,        15 from dual union all         
  select   2,          21,   201605,        9 from dual union all          
  select   2,          21,   201609,        12 from dual union all         
  select   2,          22,   201601,        9 from dual union all          
  select   2,          22,   201605,        9 from dual union all          
  select   2,          23,   201609,        9 from dual 
)
select t1.*, case when reward = 9 and grp = 1 then 1 else 0 end reward_status from (
  select t.*, sum(case when reward < 9 then 0 else 1 end) over (partition by parent_id, id order by yr_month) grp
  from t
) t1
order by parent_id, id, yr_month;
```

First, group the rows based on your condition. Here, I have used the SUM() analytic function for that purpose. Then in the outer query, simply match if 9 is the first to occur in a group.